# Ext.device.Device.openURL not working on sencha touch app

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm using sencha version 2.1.1 ,sencha cmd version v3.0.2.288. `Ext.device.Device.openURL` is not working. what can I do here? forums says that upgrading sencha will fix it, is it true? then How can I upgrade it?

Comment: according to docs of both 2.1 and 2.2 - `This currently only works on iOS using the Sencha Native Packager. Attempting to use this on PhoneGap, iOS Simulator or the browser will simply result in the current window location changing.` If you are using phonegap then you can use `navigator.app.loadUrl()` method.

Comment: tried in iOSSimulator..not working

Comment: are you using Sencha Native Packager ? if yes then i've to say it's buggy. Or perhaps try it on real device with packaged app using Sencha Native Packager.

Comment: I'm using this command `sencha app build native`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When certain button tap URLs would not open through either mobile security, or cases above where functionality is solely native, I use this snippet:

```
MyApp.Util.openLink = function(href) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    link.setAttribute('href', href);
    link.setAttribute('target','_blank');

    var clickevent = document.createEvent('Event');
    clickevent.initEvent('click', true, false);
    link.dispatchEvent(clickevent);
    return false;
};
```

I have utility functions extended off the app namespace, when required. To emulate Ext.device.Device.openURL, you can set the old window to close in your code after `MyApp.Util.openLink(href);` is called.

Comment: I have fixed that by using phonegap build. I used InAppBrowser for opening url.It worked perfectly.

Comment: Consider my answer more a dev tools tip. I'd add a variable boolean "isNative" to the app, then if statement for native only code or workarounds. Using a specific comment before and after the workaround only parts, it could all be stripped away using Ant for production builds.